# Ingress isn't working after migrating from Skaffold and manifests to DevSpace and component charts

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, devspace

I've been toying with DevSpace with Helm charts and possibly migrating to it from Skaffold and Kubernetes manifests. I can't seem to get the ingress controller working for local development: comes back with `404 Not Found`. I can reach it via port-forwarding, however, at `localhost:3000`.

Like I've always done, I [installed the `ingress-nginx` controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-desktop) first for `docker-desktop` with:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Then in my `devspace.yaml` I have the following:

```
version: v1beta10

images:
  client:
    image: app/client
    dockerfile: client/Dockerfile
    context: client/

deployments:
- name: client
  helm:
    componentChart: true
    values:
      containers:
      - image: app/client
      service:
        ports:
          - port: 3000
      ingress:
        name: ingress
        rules: 
        - host: localhost
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          servicePort: 3000
          serviceName: client
dev:
  ports:
  - name: client
    imageSelector: app/client
    forward:
    - port: 3000
      remotePort: 3000
  sync:
  - name: client
    imageSelector: app/client
    localSubPath: ./client
    excludePaths: 
    - .git/
    - node_modules/
```

The `Dockerfile` is the same for both configurations.

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
ENV CI=true
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Furthermore, I've noticed as I add services (e.g. `/api`, `/admin`, etc.) with corresponding `ingress.rules`, it creates as an ingress for each service instead of just one for the entire application.

For reference, this is what I used to do with `skaffold` and manifests:

```
# ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: ingress-dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

```
# client.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: client
      environment: development
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: client
        environment: development
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: client
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: client
    environment: development
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

```
# skaffold.yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta1
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: client
    context: client
    sync:
      manual:
      - src: 'src/**/*.js'
        dest: .
      - src: 'src/**/*.jsx'
        dest: .
      - src: 'package.json'
        dest: .
      - src: 'public/**/*.html'
        dest: .
      - src: 'src/assets/sass/**/*.scss'
        dest: .
      - src: 'src/build/**/*.js'
        dest: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  local:
    push: false
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/ingress.yaml 
      - k8s/client.yaml
```

I prefer using the `ingress` controller during development instead of port-forwarding. That way I can I just go to `localhost/`, `localhost/admin`, `localhost/api`, etc. I've run into serious bugs before that didn't come up using port-forwarding, but do with the ingress controller, so I just don't trust it.

Any suggestions for:

1. Getting the ingress working so that it is reaching the service?
2. Setting up the `devspace.yaml` so that it creates one ingress instead of one for each service?

---

The `devspace render`:

```
---
# Source: component-chart/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "client"
  labels:
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": "client"
    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/chart": "component-chart-0.8.2"
spec:
  externalIPs:
  ports:
    - name: "port-0"
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: "TCP"
  selector:
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": "devspace-app"
    "app.kubernetes.io/component": "client"
  type: "ClusterIP"
---
# Source: component-chart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "client"
  labels:
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": "devspace-app"
    "app.kubernetes.io/component": "client"
    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/chart": "component-chart-0.8.2"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      "app.kubernetes.io/name": "devspace-app"
      "app.kubernetes.io/component": "client"
      "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        "app.kubernetes.io/name": "devspace-app"
        "app.kubernetes.io/component": "client"
        "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm"
      annotations:
        "helm.sh/chart": "component-chart-0.8.2"
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      nodeSelector:
        null
      nodeName:
        null
      affinity:
        null
      tolerations:
        null
      dnsConfig:
        null
      hostAliases:
        null
      overhead:
        null
      readinessGates:
        null
      securityContext:
        null
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        null
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
      ephemeralContainers:
        null
      containers:
        - image: "croner-app/client:AtrvTRR"
          name: "container-0"
          command:
          args:
          env:
            null
          envFrom:
            null
          securityContext:
            null
          lifecycle:
            null
          livenessProbe:
            null
          readinessProbe:
            null
          startupProbe:
            null
          volumeDevices:
            null
          volumeMounts:
      initContainers:
      volumes:
  volumeClaimTemplates:
---
# Source: component-chart/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "ingress"
  labels:
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": "client"
    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/chart": "component-chart-0.8.2"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "localhost"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: client
          servicePort: 3000
        path: "/"
        pathType: "Prefix"
---
```

The biggest difference I can see is what I used to use is `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1` and the `devspace` one is `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`. Perhaps the ingress controller `controller-v1.0.0` I'm applying isn't compatible? Not sure...

Comment: You trying to connect an Ingress with host `localhost`? How's that supposed to work?

Comment: @SYN Usually fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the solution was to use an older version of the `ingress-nginx` controller that is compatible with the version used by DevSpace. In my case, I was using `devspace v5.16.0-alpha.0` and the following controller works with it:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.49.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Since this solution will change with newer versions of `devspace` and `ingress-nginx`, in general:

- Make sure the `ingress-nginx` controller version and the `devspace` version are compatible.
- Check `devspace render` to see how ingress config is being generated and that the `apiVersion` is compatible with ingress controller version you `kubectl apply`.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, you may want to run `devspace render` which shows the plain manifests that DevSpace generates from the Helm chart before deploying them to the cluster. That way you can see what is different compared to your skaffold manifests. Alternatively, you could check inside the cluster using these commands:

```
kubectl get service --all -o yaml   # to see all services
kubectl get ingress --all -o yaml   # to see all ingresses
```

My educated guess for the actual cause of your problem would be: Since you're are using `componentChart: true`, you should not specify `serviceName: client` for the ingress. I assume that this serviceName is not matching to the name of the service that the component chart generates based on the release name for the helm deployment. So just remove `serviceName: client` from devspace.yaml. Alternatively, you could specify `name: client` for the service to make sure it matches.

For the full component-chart spec, see the documentation: https://devspace.sh/component-chart/docs/configuration/reference

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I tried a few iterations including with and without `serviceName` with the same results.  I'll explore the `devspace render` and `-o yaml` to see what that shows.

Comment: I updated my original question with the output from `devpsace render`... Wondering if the `apiVersion` could be the issue, maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is very likely it. Which version of DevSpace are you using? I think only the newest one support automatic usage of `networking.k8s.io/v1`. Additionally, you may need to add an annotation (also possible via component chart ingress and then annotations: [] as key under it)
`annotations: \n  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

Comment: I switched to `v5.16.0-alpha.0` this morning to get around the [`pathType` bug](https://github.com/loft-sh/devspace/issues/1637). I'll give the annotation a shot in the morning, but thought the default class was `nginx`. Also, I'll see about using an older version of the ingress controller.

Comment: Yep that was it. Using this controller version worked: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.49.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`